# TreeMap how does it sort

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

How does the `TreeMap` sort? say for example you have the following map:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<>();
treemap.put("lol", 1);
treemap.put("Marc", 2);
treemap.put("Jesper", 3);

Iterator ittwo = treemap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (ittwo.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)ittwo.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    ittwo.remove();
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Jesper = 3
Marc = 2
lol = 1
```

So if its not alphabetically what is it then?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not only alphabetical, but it is also upper/down case sensitive.

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
treemap.put("Lol", 1);
treemap.put("Marc", 2);
treemap.put("Jesper", 3);
treemap.put("lol1", 1);
treemap.put("marc1", 2);
treemap.put("jesper1", 3);
```

Output:

```
Jesper = 3
Lol = 1
Marc = 2
jesper1 = 3
lol1 = 1
marc1 = 2
```

So, if you don't need it, you can use your custom comparator, and compare string in lower case:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());
    }
});
treemap.put("Lol", 1);
treemap.put("Marc", 2);
treemap.put("Jesper", 3);
treemap.put("lol1", 1);
treemap.put("marc1", 2);
treemap.put("jesper1", 3);
```

Output:

```
Jesper = 3
jesper1 = 3
Lol = 1
lol1 = 1
Marc = 2
marc1 = 2
```

Comment: `new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
            }
        }`

Comment: Java 8: `new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2))`

Comment: It's not just uppercase/lowercase but also lexicographically. So best to pass comparator.

Answer (score 7):

As [stated in the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) a `TreeMap` "...is sorted according to the natural ordering of its **keys**..." (emphasis is mine).

Thus your result is correct, in the light that lower case `l` is *after* uppercase `M` in the UTF "alphabet".

Should you wish to override the default behavior, you can supply a `Comparator` to the `TreeMap` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

As you did not pass any `Comparator` through the constructor, so this will construct a new `TreeMap` using the natural ordering of its keys.

In java the natural order means `lexicographical` order.

Answer (score 2):

you are in fact getting the correct output.

```
J(uppercase J)>M(uppercase M)>l(lowercase l).
```

uppercase letters are lexcographically greater than lower case letters