# Sorting a hashmap in reverse order using Double

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I know there are a number of posts that describe how to sort a hashmap in reverse. I've tried them and I've struggled to make it work. I'm relatively new to Java.

Below, I can print the hashmap in order from lowest double to highest double, but how do I sort it so the highest double comes first?
I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535050/sort-hashmap-in-reverse) unsuccessfully.

I want to sort the following in reverse order the hashMap called "lines":

```
public void sortResults(HashMap<Double, TextObject> lines) {
    Map<Double,TextObject> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Double,TextObject>(lines);
    
    
    
    System.out.println("**************************************");
        for (Map.Entry<Double, TextObject> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                                      + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Use a reverse order comparator to initialize your TreeMap, for example. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TreeMap how does it sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642636/treemap-how-does-it-sort)

Comment: Hi, check this out https://www.baeldung.com/java-treemap#custom-sorting-in-treemap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `TreeMap` with reverse comparator and then use `putAll` to add `lines`

```
Map<Double,TextObject> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Double,TextObject>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

sortedMap.putAll(lines);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!!!! I used @DeadPool's advice and it worked.